# ADODB SQL string gives me an error

Tags: sql, vba, adodb

```
StartDate3 = Format(StartDate1, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
EndDate3 = Format(EndDate1, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")

Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set sqlConnect = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

sqlConnect.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="SOURCE";Persist Security Info=False;"

cn.Open sqlConnect

rs.ActiveConnection = cn

Sql = "SELECT * FROM [tblDatabase] WHERE [Meldt Dato] BETWEEN '" & StartDate3 & "' AND '" & EndDate3 & "';"

rs.Open Sql, cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

With rs

End With
```

It gives me an error in Norwegian, so I am not sure what it would say in english, but roughly translated it says "No agreement between datatypes in expression" or something like that :p

Comment: is [Meldt Dato] the same data type as StartDate3 and EndDate3? If you're trying to compare an int to a datetime (for example) then you're likely to see this issue

Comment: Do i spy single quotation marks around your date(')? They strike me a bit odd. What I normally use is something like
" BETWEEN #01/0/2016 00:05:00#   AND    #02/02/2016 10:00:50#  ", although that might not work with the expression returned by StartDate3 & EndDate3

Comment: Try setting `StartDate3` and `EndDate3` with `CDate` to make sure they're of date type

Comment: Looks like it's a MS Access DB so if `[Meldt Dato]` is of date datatype, begin by surrounding your dates with `#` instead of `'` (quote)

Comment: I ended up with this:
Sql = "SELECT * FROM [tblDatabase] WHERE [Meldt Dato] BETWEEN #" & StartDate1 & " 00:00:00# AND # " & EndDate1 & " 00:00:00#;"

And it seems to be working :) Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed code to:

```
Sql = "SELECT * FROM [tblDatabase] WHERE [Meldt Dato] BETWEEN #" & StartDate1 & " # AND # " & EndDate1 & " #;"
```

And that seemed to do it!

Comment: You marked your own answer as the solution, when the other answer helped you get there, I don't understand that???

Answer (score 1):

You don't need this `00:00:00`, the hash `#` tags are the key.